# why i can't create the database automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='******')
db_name=['Cinfos', 'Holders', 'Capitals','Dividends','Fi_Dis','Finances']   
for db in db_name:
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("create database  if not exit %s" %db)
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
```

I got the error :
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; chec
k the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'exit Cinfos' at line 1")
What is the matter with my pymysql code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your query.

```
cur.execute("create database  if not exit %s" %db)
```

should be:

```
cur.execute("create database  if not exists %s" %db)
```

Comment: You mean, "IF NOT EXISTS"

Comment: @JBWhitmore - thanks for spotting. Correcting a typo with a typo, now that shouldn't happen... :)

Comment: I think it's a law of nature. :)